# JOIN Запрос где ORDER BY (Yii)

Tags: yii

С фреймворкам yii только начал работать. Имеются 3 вида продукта, у каждой своя таблица:

1. deposit_block
2. deposit_unblock
3. deposit_normal
4. Элемент списка

Ещё есть таблица выносов "clients" которая определяет вывод на страница пользователю свой продукт. (это работает правильно)

Ещё есть таблица выносов "withdrawal"

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`withdrawal`(`id`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`product_type`tinyint(1) NOT NULL,`product_id`int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;`

Требуется для каждого продукта вытащить свою запись последного выноса. из "[b]withdrawal[/b]"

Запрос построил так, на сколько верно?`->select('t.*, c.*, w.months, w.amount as w_amount')
->from('deposit_block t')
->join('clients c','t.client_id = c.id')
->join('withdrawal w','t.id = w.product_id')
->where('t.id=:id and w.product_type = 1', array(':id'=>$id))
->queryRow();`

Но не понимаю как надо добавить что бы из таблицы "[b]withdrawal[/b]" бралось бы последная запись продукта.
Если прописать "->order('w.id DESC')" тогда он сортирует все записи вроде по АД выноса, но под таблицу продукта. (т.е. не верно.)

Тут что-ли запрос надо переписать так что бы SELECT в SELECT был бы... Подругому никак? Если так как переписать тогда

Надеюсь понятно составил задачу проблемы.

спс.Ув.

Answer (score 1):

В Yii реализирован [ORM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM), а именно [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord).

Вот [коротенькая сводка](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr), классы моделей можно сгенерировать с помощью [Gii](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.gii)

При таком подходе вам нужно будет указать limit в построении атрибута with для выбора первичной сущности из БД.

Если же все таки решите делать с помощью [CDbCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand), то просто спрашивайте о построении SQL-запроса, не указывайте [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), т.к. вы не используете функционал фреймворка

Comment: ясн. спс большое (( Но вмоём случае как можно подправить запрос? limit мне де даст только 1 запись, а мне надо именно последную т.е. ORDER вставить.

И ещё если у меня "select('t.*, c.*, w.months, w.amount as w_amount')
" и мне надо выташить все поля из "c", только вот одно поле переопередлит через AS, т.к. название поле одинаковое в 2 таблицах, но другие поля оставить как есть по именам.